# Java:User Enter Antilog Base issue?

Tags: java

I'm finding anti-logarithm of enter values.Answer will be right with natural log base.But when try to find anti-log with enter base.then it doesn't give correct answer such as
 `anti-log value 10 with base 10 = 10000000000`

This is my code:

```
    public class A {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System. in );
    double value, res, value2, res2;
    System.out.print("Enter Anti Log Value:");
    value = s.nextDouble();
    res = Math.exp(value);
    System.out.println("Answer Of Antilog With natural Base is: + res);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Enter Your Base:");
    value2 = s.nextDouble();
    res2 = Math.exp(value) / Math.exp(value2);
    System.out.println("Answer Of Antilog With your enter Base is : " + res2);
}
}
```

It give answer with enter base 10 = 1.0 so how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correct you should simply replace

```
res2 = Math.exp(value) / Math.exp(value2);
```

with

```
res2 = Math.pow(value2, value);
```

If you want to avoid scientific notation when printing the value, use:

```
System.out.printf("Answer Of Antilog With your enter Base is : %f%n", res2 );
```

or (to skip the decimals):

```
System.out.printf("Answer Of Antilog With your enter Base is : %.0f%n", res2 );
```

Comment: i think he is taking the log so no need of pow

Comment: @K Erlandsson i grab that answer but it's write in this 1.0E10.is there a way that i can show answer like this 10000000000

Comment: @hamel123 That is just a formatting issue, java formats large numbers that way per default. You can use `System.out.printf("Answer Of Antilog With your enter Base is : %f\n", res2 );` to print the number without scientific notation.

Comment: @K Erlandsson  what does printf  and %f\n mean

Comment: @hamel123 since it is out of the scope for this question I'll just give you a link to the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html